# How to change nav-link hover color for just one specific link?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and I have a navbar with some links that use the nav-link class as well as a sidebar navigation that uses nav-link. I need to change the hover color for one link in particular. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Target it with CSS selector

Comment: Thanks. How do you do that exactly?

Comment: Do you understand CSS selectors? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I was trying to add an additional class to it called holdbackhover and set the transparency for that like this: .nav-link>.holdbackhover>a:hover{background-color:transparent;}

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working though.

Answer (score 0):

You can go either with nth-child or by defining class.

css:

```
    .navbar{
  &:nth-child(1){
    .nav-item{
      &:nth-child(2){
        .nav-link{
          color:#000;
          &:hover{
            color:blue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Else go can go with class or Id Selector:

```
.hover{
 .nav-link{
           &:hover{
            color:green !important;
          }
        }
}
```

Fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/cruv2bzu/3/)

Defining a class may be simpler to change / identify, If you dont want to add an extra class you can use nth-child selector

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to add an additional class to it called holdbackhover and set the transparency for that like this: .nav-link>.holdbackhover>a:hover{background-color:transparen‌​t;}

It should be

```
.nav-link.holdbackhover:hover {
   background-color:transparen‌​t;
   color:red; // or what ever
}
```